# strange warning on my tests

Tags: python, django, warnings, translation

I installed a "third party app" named *rosetta* on my project for manage my translations more "systematic" way from this command:

```
sudo easy_install django-rosetta
```

I don't have any problem with rosetta, i can manage my translations very well with its interface but i have been watching at my console that when i restart my test

```
/manage.py runserver
```

and refresh the rosetta interface, i obtain this issue:

> /home/user/PROJECT/AMBIENTE1/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/template/base.py:290:
>   RemovedInDjango18Warning: 'The `cycle` template tag is changing to
>   escape its arguments; the non-autoescaping version is deprecated. Load
>   it from the `future` tag library to start using the new behavior.
>   compiled_result = compile_func(self, token)

This problem only appears when i refresh my browser with rosetta open, on the other hand if i refresh the website (my project) or my admin panel nothing appears...

My project really runs perfectly but i have that question...

Thanks for any answer

Have a great day!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The author of the django-rosetta package needs to update the use of the cycle tag.

What the warning means is that the Django developers have identified a problem with the way cycle is being used by the current version of django-rosetta, and they plan to remove that functionality in a future release. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/releases/1.9/#cycle-syntax-with-comma-separated-arguments

Generally speaking, you can ignore warnings like this for now. It will become a problem when you upgrade to a version of Django where the deprecated feature is removed or no longer supported.